# Exception class for objects of different classes

Tags: java, exception, constructor

I'd like to write an exception class which is usable with different classes and specific behaviors. It works well with changing an object - like

```
a.setWeight(500)
```

- but it doesn't work in my constructor - like

```
Cheese b = new Cheese(500);
```

because the object is not being generated and null is inserted in my WeightException.

```
public class WeightException extends Exception {
        private int attribute;
        private Object object;

        public WeightException(Object o, int a) throws WeightException {
            object = o;
            attribute = a;
        }

        public String getMessage() {
            if(object instanceof Cheese)
            return "Cheese is overweight.";

            if(object instanceof Baggage)
                return "Baggage is "+String.valueOf(attribute)+" kilos overweight.";
        }
    }

    public class Cheese {
    private int weight;

    public Cheese(int weight) {
    setWeight(weight);
    }

    public void setWeight(int weight) throws WeightException {
    if(weight<200)
    this.weight = weight;
    else
    throw new WeightException(this, weight);
    }
    }
```

Does anybody know a better approach to solve this than to insert a string with the class name in my exception class parameters?

Comment: You need the `throws` clause in your constructor, too. This is what you are talking about?

Comment: Since you're throwing inside the constructor, `this` is not a valid reference.

Comment: @SJuan76 No, I've just forgotten that.

Comment: @TomG: Why not? At the very least, is it not a valid reference to an invalid `Cheese` instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution which would require that you use [a "toy" project of mine](https://github.com/fge/msg-simple) (well, I already use it in other projects):

Make a base abstract class like this:

```
public abstract class WeightedItem
{
    protected static final MessageBundle BUNDLE;

    static {
        // The day when you get serious, replace with a properties bundle
        final MessageSource source = MapMessageSource.newBuilder()
            .put(Cheese.class.getCanonicalName(), "cheese is overweight")
            .put(Baggage.class.getCanonicalName(), "baggage is %d kilos overweight")
            .build();

        BUNDLE = MessageBundle.newBuilder().appendSource(source).freeze();
    }

    protected int weight;

    protected final WeightException doException(final Object... params)
    {
        return new WeightException(BUNDLE.printf(getClass().getCanonicalName(),
            params));
    }
}
```

An implementation of `Baggage` would then do:

```
public class Baggage
    extends WeightedItem
{
    // ....

    public void setWeight(int weight)
        throws WeightException
    {
        if (overweight)
            throw doException(weight);
    }
}
```

As the implementation is both key-resistant (returns the key if missing) and format-resistant (returns the format string itself if format argument mismatch) you are guaranteed to have parameterized messages or quickly see where you got your messages wrong...

Comment: I solved this problem kind of like your approach: I created an abstract class and two sub classes, with an abstract function which puts out the message.

Answer (score 2):

- Implement an interface in the classes you want to use with this exception.
- The interface has a method to define a message, possible another to provide an attribute.
- Alternatively, provide an array of attributes and use `String.format` to build the message.
- Use that interface to define the object parameter passed in to the exception ctor.
- Call that method in the exception to get the message.

Personally, I find this to be an anti-pattern, unless the classes you want to use with the exception are very tightly related. Otherwise you're giving up semantically-meaningful exception property names.

I'd rather see an app-specific superclass with subclasses with semantic meaning.

Comment: Agreed that this is a serious anti-pattern. Instanceof switching generally indicates a poor approximation of proper object orientation.

Comment: This might be the best solution for my problem, but it's overpowered in my case (I just have this two classes and those are built simply.)

Comment: @DanielaKessler Hence the "what I'd rather see" part. Without knowing you didn't *really* need to solve the problem you described it was unlikely you'd get an *optimal* solution, which is a *balance* of factors.

Answer (score 0):

Have you actually tried running this code? The `this` variable is valid (non-null) within a constructor. Even if the constructor throws an exception, a new object has been created and can be referenced. See the [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.9.4).

Comment: " The this variable is valid (non-null) within a constructor.  The this variable is valid (non-null) within a constructor. " <-- maybe, but ouch

Comment: @fge: Yes, it's a classic example of what not to do, because it's a great way to leak a reference to an uninitialized object. But still, theoretically it ought to work for OP's purposes.

Answer (score 0):

If you parameterize the exception with everything you need for the message, you can rid yourself of using `instanceof`, and make the exception usable by any class:

Also, it's not a good idea to hold a reference to the object that caused the exception - it's unnecessary, is a form of memory leak, but importantly if the exception is thrown from the constructor, will allow `this` to "escape" from the constructor (always bad).

```
public class WeightException extends Exception {
    private final int attribute;
    private final String className;
    private final String units;

    public WeightException(Object o, int a) {
        this(o, a, null);
    }

    public WeightException(Object o, int a, String u) {
        classname = o.getClass().getSimpleName(); // eg "Cheese"
        attribute = a;
        units = u == null ? "" : u + " ";
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return className " is " + attribute + " " + units + "overweight.";
    }
}
```

You can now use this exception with any class without further modification of the exception or the client class, other than to provide the optional units:

From `Cheese`:

```
throw new WeightException(this, weight);
```

From `Baggage`:

```
throw new WeightException(this, weight, "kilos");
```